# Map Array in C - Linked List w/ Key: Value

Tags: c, dictionary, linked-list, associative-array

Ok my issue is when I write the node it just overwrites the head node, so when you call map_get you only get one node with data.  I want to hand the data on the head or push the head node and hang it front either works, whatever one is the easiest would be best thanks for your help.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include "map.h"
#include <string.h>
int main(){
map_t* newList = malloc(sizeof(map_t));
map_init(newList);
const char* passString ="a";
const char* secondString="2";
map_put(newList,"3","3");
map_put(newList,"7","34");
map_put(newList,"a","45");
map_put(newList,passString,secondString);
map_get(newList,secondString);
}

void map_init(map_t* self) {
map_entry_t* newNode= malloc(sizeof(map_entry_t)); // allocate
self->size = 0;
self->entry = newNode; // link next
}

int map_put(map_t* self, const char* key, const char* val) {
  assert(self != NULL);
map_entry_t* current;
//current = self->entry->key;
while(current->next != NULL){
    current = current->next;

}
self->entry->key = key;
self->entry->value = val;
map_entry_t* newNode = malloc(sizeof(map_entry_t));


printf("\ntry printing the list \n");
printf(self->entry->key);
printf(" :was the key and the value is \n");
printf(self->entry->value);
printf("\n");


}

const char* map_get(map_t* self, const char* key) {
  assert(self != NULL);
const char* target = key;
int i=0;
for(i; i<=self->size; i++) 
{
printf("\n\ninside the list\n");
printf(self->entry->value);
printf("\n");
}
}

int map_size(map_t* self) {
  assert(self != NULL);

}

int map_remove(map_t* self, const char* key) {
  assert(self != NULL);

}

int map_serialize(map_t* self, FILE* stream) {
  assert(self != NULL);

}

int map_deserialize(map_t* self, FILE* stream) {
  assert(self != NULL);

}

void map_destroy(map_t* self) {
  assert(self != NULL);

}


map.h

    #ifndef __A1_MAP_H__
#define __A1_MAP_H__

#include <stdio.h>

#define SYS_ERROR -1
#define OK 0
#define KEY_EXISTS 1
#define NO_KEY_EXISTS 2

// Strange type definition due to the recursive nature
//   of the struct. This technique is called 'forward
//   declaration' and is necessary for compilation reasons.
typedef struct _map_entry map_entry_t;
struct _map_entry {
  char* key;
  char* value;
  map_entry_t* next;
} ;

typedef struct _map {
  map_entry_t* entry;
  int size;
} map_t;

// Part one functions.
void map_init(map_t*);
int map_put(map_t*, const char*, const char*);
const char* map_get(map_t*, const char*);
int map_remove(map_t*, const char*);
int map_size(map_t*);
void map_destroy(map_t*);

// Part two functions. 
int map_serialize(map_t*, FILE*);
int map_deserialize(map_t*, FILE*);

#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

In `map_put`, you should initialize `current` to point at the head of the list `self`. Right now, it starts pointing ... somewhere ... in memory, and then you try to walk a list from there.  You then completely ignore that and write directly into the head element of the list (`self`) instead of a new node (`newNode`). You'll also need to then set a link from current to your new node.

Comment: I know what needs to happen I dont know what it looks like in code, I know that I either need to append to the head node which should be easier or I need to push the head node and push onto the stack a new node.  I would rather do it in append mode, could someone please show me the proper way to add the nodes by appending them

Comment: You initialize a variable by using `=`, as in `current = self`.  You need to change all the copying to `self->`things and use `newNode` instead, since after all that's why it exists (to be the new node).  Then you need to set the `next` field in `current` to point to your new node so that the thing actually gets into your list.

Comment: can you provide an example i have made some changes after i read my code and seen some of the points you just spoke of myself. I had to think about how a list works now the only issue is actually getting it to hang it on the new node. ill reupload the code and you please provide an example of node adding

Comment: I added the code here on github   https://github.com/psychotiic/MapArray.c/blob/master/A1_Map/map.c